# Adding Integers to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, linked-list

I have an `ArrayList` of `LinkedList`s (an array of linked lists). The `LinkedList`s contains integers (`Integer`).

```
private List<LinkedList> buckets;
buckets = new ArrayList<LinkedList>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    LinkedList<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    buckets.add(temp);
}
```

I later want to remove the items from the linked list (in the order they were added) and add them to an array list. When I try this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<Integer>(unsorted.size());
for (int i = 0; i < buckets.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < buckets.get(i).size(); j++) {
        sorted.add(buckets.get(j).removeLast());
        // sorted.add((Integer)buckets.get(j).removeLast());
    }
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
add(java.lang.Integer) in ArrayList cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object)
```

But when I cast it to an `Integer` (the commented out line), the array is full of `null values`. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Here is where I am adding items to `bucket`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.size(); i++) {
    int digit = (unsorted.get(i) / position) % 10;
    buckets.get(digit).add(unsorted.get(i));
}
```

Note that `sorted` is an `ArrayList<Integer>`. When I trace it in debug mode, I can see that the LinkedLists have Integer objects with the correct values.

Screenshot of buckets contents:

[image: Bucket contents debug output]

Working Example:

```
class Ideone {
    private static List<LinkedList<Integer>> buckets;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arr.add(6);
        arr.add(8);
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(3);
        arr.add(9);
        System.out.println(arr);
        arr = sort(arr);
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> sort(ArrayList<Integer> unsorted) {
        buckets = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            LinkedList<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            buckets.add(temp);
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<Integer>(unsorted.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.size(); i++) {
            int digit = unsorted.get(i) % 10;
            buckets.get(digit).add(unsorted.get(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < buckets.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buckets.get(i).size(); j++) {
                sorted.add(buckets.get(j).poll());
                // sorted.add((Integer)buckets.get(j).removeLast());
            }
        }
        return sorted;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you declare `buckets` as `List<LinkedList<Integer>> buckets` this will work.  Slightly better would be to use `List<List<Integer>> buckets`.

Comment: Thank you, I have done this and it fixes the error, but I am still getting null values.

Comment: Please re-read the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link and protocol. You should not post links but actual working code here with your question.

Comment: Gotcha, I will do that from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your nested loop,

```
  for (int i = 0; i < buckets.size(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < buckets.get(i).size(); j++) {

        // ***** here *****
        sorted.add(buckets.get(j).poll());

     }
  }
```

You look to be polling the wrong List.

Try changing

```
sorted.add(buckets.get(j).poll());
```

to:

```
sorted.add(buckets.get(i).poll());
```

Perhaps a cleaner more intuitive way to code this would be something like:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < buckets.size(); i++) {
     LinkedList<Integer> innerList = buckets.get(i);
     for (int j = 0; j < innerList.size(); j++) {
        sorted.add(innerList.poll());
     }
  }
```

Although this may not work if the innerList has multiple items. Why not instead remove items safely with an iterator?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < buckets.size(); i++) {
     LinkedList<Integer> innerList = buckets.get(i);
     for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = innerList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        sorted.add(iterator.next());
        iterator.remove(); // this guy is optional
     }
  }
```

Either that or simply `use get(j)`

```
  for (int i = 0; i < buckets.size(); i++) {
     LinkedList<Integer> innerList = buckets.get(i);
     for (int j = 0; j < innerList.size(); j++) {
        sorted.add(innerList.get(j));
     }
  }
```

Although this isn't efficient use of a LinkedList

Comment: Thank you! My `i` and `j` variables were switched. That simple edit did the trick. Although, both of your suggestions make the code much clearer and easier to understand, so I will use on of those implementations instead. Out of curiosity, is there a benefit to using an iterator instead of looping through the size?

Comment: @SFBA26: The iterator is a more natural fit for a LinkedList since it does not involve the random access needed for a call to `get(...)`. The iterator helps avoid a concurrent modification exception if you remove items from within the loop. Finally your `poll()` code will not work if the buckets have more than one item in them.

Comment: If `remove()` is optional, why not just use a for-each loop: `for (Integer j in buckets.get(i)) {...}`?

Answer (score 4):

You are using the raw form of `LinkedList` here:

```
private List<LinkedList> buckets;
```

Because of this, `removeLast` will return `Object`, not `Integer`.  Try

```
private List<LinkedList<Integer>> buckets;
```

and

```
buckets = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
```

Casting the return of `removeLast` to `Integer` was the pre-generics way of getting this to work.  However, you never inserted any items into each `LinkedList`, so `removeLast` returns `null`.  If you want something returned, first insert something into each `LinkedList` that gets inserted into `buckets`.

Casting to `Integer` would still work, but supplying `Integer` as the type argument to `LinkedList` is preferred, especially since you are using generics by supplying `LinkedList` as the type parameter to `List` already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Adding <Integer> got rid of the error, but I am still getting null values. I am actually adding values to the LinkedList, I just didn't include the code. I have updated the question. Any ideas why I am still getting null?

Answer (score 0):

The item that you inserted into the ArrayList "sorted" is the item you took from the link list LinkedList.

But you never actually add any item to it. You simply just created a LinkedList and added it to your bucket list.

You need to add something into the temp list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    LinkedList<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    // Add something to the temp LinkedList
    buckets.add(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am actually adding values to the LinkedList, I just didn't include the code. I have updated the question. Any ideas why I am still getting null?

Comment: I added a screenshot with the contents of `bucket`.